# unmet dependencies running apt-get upgrade after installing python3 to /opt

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, python, python3

I am on 16.04. I installed python 3.6.0 to /opt/python3.6 (it is not on my path) and when I try to run `apt-get upgrade` it tells me that I have a lot of unmet dependencies that depend on python <= 2.8 but 3.6.0-1 is installed...

for example...

```
 python-cffi-backend : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.0-1 is installed
```

but I don't see how this is affecting `apt-get upgrade` because the python3.6 is not in my path... I can verify that `python --version` outputs `2.7.12` and `python3 --version` ooutputs `3.5.2` which is what ships with ubuntu.

So how is this out-of-path 3.6 install affecting upgrades?

EDIT (output of `apt-cache policy python`):

```
python:
  Installed: 3.6.0-1
  Candidate: 3.6.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.0-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.11-1 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy python`?

Comment: @muru, added to post. It seems to be finding it but IDK how